# How many http get requests/minute can we get without being considered attack/spam

Tags: http, python-requests

Let's say we have a url fuzzer for security testing writen in Python.

How many Get requests can we have per second or minute without affecting that website ?

For example: Are 200 Requests/Minute too much ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no fixed amount, it totally depends on the website.

Sometimes the HTTP response status code can help you to understand that using the 429 status code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Comment: You are right. Anyway, is there an average ? Approximately ?

Comment: Average is not a good index, as there are sites that can go low to less than 100 req/s and sites that are good with more than 1000 req/s
I would consider more what is a good rate for what you have to do. Maybe you can find a strategy to maximize the rate you do to ALL the sites you need to call, trying to minimize the rate that a single site will receive